# Property to force launching in full screen

Tags: macos, fullscreen, plist

Is there any property that forces an application to start in full screen if it supports it?

I noticed in `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.mycompany.myapp.savedState/windows.plist` there's a key that saves the window state on some applications.

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIsFullScreen</key>
        <true/>
```

Some applications write it while open but don't save it and then start again not in full screen. And locking `windows.plist` will log an error and the app will still launch in a window.